# Java Stack Introspection

Tags: java, security, jvm, securitymanager

I was hoping that someone can help me with the following:

My understanding about java stack introspection (maybe a bit oversimplified here) is that a process generates a stack frame that is then added to the stack. Now when the process needs to make a system call the stack introspection algorithm checks to see whether the principal (i.e. the process that is trying to access a resource) is allowed to use the particular resource and then annotates the frame accordingly (granting or forbidding access).

My questions are:

1. Is the above correct or am I missing something?
2. How does the JVM decide whether to grant or restrict access? Is the user involved in this decision?
3. In [this study](http://sip.cs.princeton.edu/pub/oakland98.pdf) theres an example (figure 2) in which a frame inherits/is being told the "belief set" of the previous frame! What stops malicious code from being executed in this example (i.e. get access to a resource that shouldnt have accesss to)?

Comment: @NiklasB. Its probably not an issue and I suppose it wasnt even back then but I just cant see how it works!(i.e. what prevents it from executing malicious code)

Comment: Okay, no worries :) It's an interesting question.

Comment: The fundamental Java intra-stack security mechanism is [doPrivileged](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged(java.security.PrivilegedAction)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the JVM decide whether to grant or restrict access? Is the user involved in this decision?

It delegates to the currently installed `SecurityManager`.

> Is the above correct or am I missing something?

The `SecurityManager` can introspect on the stack, or it can use some other criteria.  The `SecurityManager` associated with applets that run in the browser does introspect so this is right in at least one domain.

> In this study theres an example (figure 2) in which a frame inherits/is being told the "belief set" of the previous frame! What stops malicious code from being executed in this example (i.e. get access to a resource that shouldnt have accesss to)?

Nothing really.  Java security is a mess and many recommend turning java off in browsers since few legit sites use it these days.

["Sun Java by far the most vulnerable plug-in"](http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=10617) from 2010.